# no REST API logs in kafka connect

Tags: log4j, apache-kafka-connect

It's Confluent version 5.5.4 and I wanted to write the REST logs to file.

When I tested with version 5.2.0, I could see the REST logs in my connect worker logs.
At that time, my log4j properties was:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, logFile
    
log4j.appender.logFile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logFile.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.logFile.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/connect.log
log4j.appender.logFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logFile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c:%L)%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.reflections=ERROR
```

and logs were like this:

```
[2021-04-27 18:12:04,352] INFO Committed hdfs://my/path/test2/dt=2021-04-27/1800/test2+0+0000001760+0000001774.txt for test2-0 (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter)
[2021-04-27 18:12:07,818] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=test2-4} Committing offsets asynchronously using sequence number 12: {test2-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1774, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
[2021-04-27 18:12:11,760] INFO 10.107.122.215 - - [27/Apr/2021:09:12:11 +0000] "GET /connectors HTTP/1.1" 200 9  71 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer)
[2021-04-27 18:12:16,721] INFO Connector test3 config updated (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
[2021-04-27 18:12:16,722] INFO Rebalance started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
[2021-04-27 18:12:16,722] INFO Stopping task test2-1 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker)
[2021-04-27 18:12:16,722] INFO Stopping task test2-4 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker)
[2021-04-27 18:12:16,741] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-13, groupId=connect-test2] Member consumer-13-bf6e6283-8ab1-43eb-8b39-2b7f4c4bc1c8 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator myserver:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2021-04-27 18:12:16,743] INFO 10.107.122.215 - - [27/Apr/2021:09:12:16 +0000] "POST /connectors HTTP/1.1" 201 993  82 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer)
[2021-04-27 18:12:16,774] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-12, groupId=connect-test2] Member consumer-12-2421a72c-383b-4c3e-a402-911d56c6aa05 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator myserver:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2021-04-27 18:12:16,776] INFO Finished stopping tasks in preparation for rebalance (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
```

And now I'm using the version 5.5.4 with WAL problem fixed. While I'm using it, I'v never seen the REST logs in my logFile :( I've tried to write the logs to a separate file as setting those properties :

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, logFile

log4j.appender.logFile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logFile.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.logFile.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/connect.log
log4j.appender.logFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logFile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c:%L)%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.reflections=ERROR

log4j.appender.kafkaConnectRestAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kafkaConnectRestAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.kafkaConnectRestAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/connect-rest.log
log4j.appender.kafkaConnectRestAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaConnectRestAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=INFO, kafkaConnectRestAppender
log4j.additivity.org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=false
```

Then, I got connect-rest.log file, I made a lot of requests, but there was nothing except this:

```
[2021-05-26 01:41:52,135] INFO Added connector for http://:8083 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer)
[2021-05-26 01:41:52,135] INFO Initializing REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer)
[2021-05-26 01:41:52,204] INFO Advertised URI: http://MY_HOST_NAME:8083/ (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer)
[2021-05-26 01:41:52,204] INFO REST server listening at http://172.17.0.5:8083/, advertising URL http://MY_HOST_NAME:8083/ (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer)
[2021-05-26 01:41:52,205] INFO Advertised URI: http://MY_HOST_NAME:8083/ (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer)
[2021-05-26 01:41:52,205] INFO REST admin endpoints at http://MY_HOST_NAME:8083/ (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer)
[2021-05-26 01:41:52,205] INFO Advertised URI: http://MY_HOST_NAME:8083/ (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer)
[2021-05-26 01:41:52,451] INFO Initializing REST resources (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer)
[2021-05-26 01:41:52,509] INFO Adding admin resources to main listener (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer)
[2021-05-26 01:41:53,410] INFO REST resources initialized; server is started and ready to handle requests (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer)
```

Am I wrong with log4j properties? Or any version depending issues?

Comment: Can you show an example of the logs you'd gotten before?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I added part of old logs which are from version 5.2.0!

Comment: So, after `REST resources initialized; server is started and ready to handle requests`, you get no POST/GET logs?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Nothing after that line. That's all i got

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-14099